# How would you authorize pushes only in certain directories with Gitolite?

Tags: git, chmod, gitolite

I have a working configuration for a symfony project:

```
@admin = admin ku
@developer = sarhan dima_syrv sarhandom a_bobkov
@testers = novikov_d 

repo    dev
    - master = @admin @developer @testers
    RW+      =   @admin @developer
    RW+     =   jenkins ku
    RW      =   @testers
```

I want to make the group of testers could only write to folders Tests.
I'm doing this configuration:
    @admin = admin ku
    @developer = sarhan dima_syrv sarhandom a_bobkov
    @testers = novikov_d

```
repo    dev
    - master = @admin @developer @testers
    RW      =   @admin @developer
    RW+     =   jenkins
    RW      =   @testers
    RW NAME/ =  @admin
    RW NAME/src =   @admin @developer
    RW NAME/src/.*/.*/Tests   =   @testers
```

I have a working configuration for a symfony project
I want to make the group of testers could only write to folders Tests
I'm doing this configuration
And it gives me only part of the solution, testers can write only in Tests folder, but no one can push new branches can only record in the old branches. How to make everyone to create a new branch, while testers could only write to folders Tests?
Please help me!

Comment: So and what is the problem? No access?

Comment: Sorry for the question being closed. I suspect those "moderators" don't know much about git, even less about gitolite.

Comment: @VonC I suspect this question was closed because of the very simplistic comment: "_But it doesn't work._" OP needs to provide far more details in order for this to be a real question.

Comment: @jlordo I agree. But I prefer to edit and improve (since I know quite a bit about the topic referenced in the OP) than just close.

Comment: @VonC this question has a real chance in the reopen queue, if the OP adds some relevant information. Why are you unhappy about it being closed, you've written a detailed answer, and OP hast the chance to accept it.

Comment: @jlordo I am happy :) Don't forget the OP has been on Stack Overflow for the grand total of... 6 hours. He/she might not be completely familiar with the art of writing a good complete detailed question. Heck, even I cannot do it well... (which explains why I wrote 6K+ answers vs. 11 questions)

Comment: The reopen votes have expired, and your valid question will remain closed and downvoted by ignorant who didn't take the time to improve it. Sorry for this first contact with Stack Overflow. Try again: we are better than this.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the **`VREF NAME`**, an update hook which will deny your push if your commit impact the wrong directory or file within your repo.

See "[**restricting pushes by dir/file name**](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME)" (with gitolite version 3, or 'g3').

> The **`"NAME" VREF`** allows you to restrict pushes by the names of dirs and files changed.
>   (Side note: the `NAME VREF` is the only one directly implemented within the update hook, so you won't find it in the `VREF` directory).
>
> Here's an example. Say you don't want junior developers pushing changes to the `Makefile`, because it's quite complex:

```
repo foo
    RW+                             =   @senior_devs
    RW                              =   @junior_devs

    -   VREF/NAME/Makefile          =   @junior_devs
```

> When a senior dev pushes, the `VREF` is not invoked at all. But when a junior dev pushes, the `VREF` is invoked, and it returns a list of files changed as refs, looking like this:

```
VREF/NAME/file-1
VREF/NAME/dir-2/file-3
...etc...
```

> Each of these refs is matched against the access rules.
>   If one of them happens to be the `Makefile`, then the ref returned (`VREF/NAME/Makefile`) will match the deny rule and kill the push.

---

So you need to experiment a bit to see if that hook supports your exact scenario, but this is the official way for Gitolite to restrict push by files or dirnames.

Comment: I've tried different configurations, when I add the VREF / NAME ... or NAME ... with any parameters, one can not push

Comment: @user1943041 consider the second part of the link I mention in my answer, then: the section starting with "Another way to use this is when you know what is allowed instead of what is not allowed": that might be a closer fit to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do it. A git repository is the whole contents.

The only solution would be to have your test sources in *another* repository (and use submodules).